# I want to use Twitter Bootstrap to develop a website with the fixed container class, but client wants the website to be 980px width and not 1170px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have used Twitter Bootstrap to develop a website with the fixed container class, but now the client wants the website to be 980px width and not 1170px.

Comment: then edit `bootstrap.css` and change wherever you find `1170px` to `980px`..

Comment: i would suggest never change bootstrap.css file. You should overwrite those classes in your own styles.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div style="max-width:980px"> 
</div>
```

This will limit the size of the div to "980px" maximum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use fluid-container but nested inside some div with maximum width of 980px. (in order to be responsive)
Here is an example.

```
<div style="max-width: 980px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Here comes your HTML code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution will be

```
.container { max-width: 980px; }
```

But better one is to go http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and change @container-large-desktop variable and download customized bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change de size of class lg, put a limit to 980px; or restrict you principal container (or body) to md class